# Jquery DataTable pagination Not working when postaback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Jquery DataTable Pagination is not working I have 13 paginations i am selecting 5th pagingwhen i click edit button in my gridview the page will postback and pagination is not shows current selected(5th)page and it will directly to 1st page page. when i select any page in my pagination after postback also it is how to show current selected page

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTable/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="DataTable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $(function () {
                // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
                $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> th').each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    if (title == "A Name" || title == "  Name" || title == "ttl") {
                        $(this).html(title + '<br/><input type="text" style="width:120px" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                    }
                    else {
                        if (title != " ") {
                            //$(this).html(title + '<br/><input type="text" style="background-color:#646464;border:none" disabled="disabled"   />');
                        }
                    }
                });

                // DataTable
                var table = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info": false,
                    "pageLength": 10,
                    "bLengthChange": false

                });

                table.columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;

                    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                            that
                                .search( this.value )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            } );
 </script>
```

and Gridview :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="mydatagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        EmptyDataText="No files uploaded" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
<columns>
Some Columns
</columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

I tried with `StateSave:true` it saves only save pages again datatable is not fully load

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU6n4.png)

Can anyone please tell me
Thank you

Comment: Show your server side code, the code behind file. Are you loading any data in your 'Page_Load'? If so, check for IsPostBack in your form load event.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your server side, or the code behind file, I cannot say for certain that your problem lies here.

If you are loading your initial grid and values in the `Page_Load` event, it might be worth checking for `IsPostBack`.

Your `Page_Load` should then look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //page is being loaded in response to a client postback, so do not load initial values again
        //Do your initial loading of grid here
        YourPopulateGridMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,@monstertjie-za, I tried with your code. when i use Jquery Datatable plugin that time pagination postbacks my page will not shows current page.Here i am taking Jquery DataTable Pagination

Comment: Show me your OnRowDataBound event.

Comment: In OnRowDataBound event, i am just setting gridview styles only, `foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            tc.BorderWidth = 0;
            tc.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }`